# Docker compose error to connect postgres database with Node API

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am having the connection error with the docker-composer when I try to access a postgres database through an API in Node.

I'm using Sequelize as ORM to acess the database. But I'dont know what happened.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  api-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./api-docker.dockerfile
    image: api-service
    container_name: api-service
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
      - node_modules:/home/node/api/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - api-network
    command: npm run start:dev 

  postgres-db:
    expose:
      - ${PORT_SERVICE}
    ports:
      - ${PORT_SERVICE}:5432
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - pgReportData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${USER_SERVICE}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PASSWORD_SERVICE}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_SERVICE}
    networks:
      - api-network
    container_name: postgres-db
    image: postgres:10

networks:
  api-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  pgReportData:
    driver: local
  node_modules:
```

**.env:**

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=30780
HOST_SERVICE=postgres-db
DATABASE_SERVICE=base
USER_SERVICE=user
PASSWORD_SERVICE=password
DIALECT=postgres
PORT_SERVICE=5444
```

**api-docker.dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
COPY --chown=node:node . .
USER node
RUN npm install
EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

And when I run: 
docker-compose up

I'm getting this error:

[image]

Any ideia?

Can someone help me ??

Comment: On which port your postgre-db is running within the container? and is it accessed only by node? if so why are you mapping ports to host network? you need only to expose it to container network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If node is the only app that connects to postgre-db you can remove the networks, and expose the postgredb running port (5432). To connect to the db you can simply use the container name as host.

> Connection String: `"postgres://YourUserName:YourPassword@postgres-db:5432/YourDatabase";`

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  api-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./api-docker.dockerfile
    image: api-service
    container_name: api-service
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
      - node_modules:/home/node/api/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    command: npm run start:dev 

  postgres-db:
    expose:
      - 5432
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - pgReportData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${USER_SERVICE}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PASSWORD_SERVICE}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_SERVICE}
    container_name: postgres-db
    image: postgres:10

volumes:
  pgReportData:
    driver: local
  node_modules:
```

Comment: Thanks! I solve the problem. But now I can't reach API from Docker in Postman...using localhost

Comment: I try using http://127.0.0.1:30780/api/route and http://localhost:30780/api/route, but it didnt work.

Comment: Ensure the ports are mapped correctly on the container using `docker ps` or `docker port api-service`